# Rails select tag - set specific option style

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, html-select

I want to select one of options in SELECT tag with special color.

How to do this following using Rails' f.select helper and options_for_select ?

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    option.standard {background-color:#FFAAAA}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <select style="width:100px">
    <option selected="selected">1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option class="standard">3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation says for [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select), you can do it like this:

```
options_for_select([ 1, 2, [ 3, { :class => 'standard' }], 4, 5 ], [ 1 ])
```